# Getting variable number of inputs Using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to have input like:-
The first line of the input contains the two cities for where the listing of flight options must be produced – the departure city and the arrival city, separated by a white-space.

The next N lines will contain the available flights and their costs. Each line is a direct flight starting with the departure city name, followed by the arrival city name, and lastly followed by the cost of that flight – all three separate by a white-space character.

Where `1<=N<=20`.

Can anyone plz help I want to know how to end the input. I am using:-

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!(input = s.nextLine()).equals(" "))
```

but all in vain.

The data is in the form of

```
CityA CityB // Upto its I have done. The next N lines i.e. second paragraph is a confusion
```

Next N lines should be in form

```
CityA CityC 5000
CityA CityD 3000
```

Comment: Can you paste that date you will be scanning?

Comment: I have edited the question @JoseMartinez. Mainly I want to get input from user via console using Scanner class.

Comment: You have to use the `scanner.hasNext()` method for check available inputs

Comment: Can you plz put the code, how it will work in my case ?

Comment: **1)** Read the first line. **2)** validate the input (are there the two different Strings which represents the existing cities) **3)** You don't need to ask the user for the CityA, b/c it's always the same. **4)** read the Scanner nextLine in the loop and validate if the next line contains String (representing the City) and the cost - while the very end of input, OR until your validation doesn't fulfill the expected input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maxCount = 20;
    // initialize it to a random value for now
    String input = "?";
    System.out.println("Enter 2 cities with cost upto 20");
    while (!input.trim().equals("") && maxCount > 0) {
        input = s.nextLine();
        /*
         *  parse input accordingly
         */
        maxCount--;
    }
    System.out.println("Done with input");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    while (!(input = sc.nextLine()).equals(" ")) {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(input);
    }
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention the user entering *EXIT*. Also, System.exit(0) will terminate the whole JVM, which means that all processing done by the code till that statement will be lost.

Comment: Did you mean break? Because as said by @NicholasK System.exit(0); terminates whole of JVM

Comment: Yes break would help based on input condition (number of inputs = 20). I agree with @NicholasK.

Comment: Rightly said by @NicholasK. In my question there is nowhere mention to use "EXIT" to terminate the input.